# Restrict a page navigation to one control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making an online exam website where a user is taken to a page where there are multiple choice questions. I want to set it up so that once a user navigates to this exam page, he cannot navigate back. The only way he can get out of it is by clicking the submit button and then he cannot access that page again. The questions on the exam page are in an SQL database. I have everything done, the only thing I need help with is restricting the navigation of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using `Session` varaible.If u have 3 pages say a.aspx,b.aspx,c.aspx then create 3 session variables such as

> Session["a"]="some value";Session["b"]="some value";Session["c"]="some value";

On the pageload of the a.aspx check if the session contains value or null.If it is null then u can make sure that it is the first time that page is loaded else do what you want to do if user tries to visit a page which is already viewed.

Please try this code

```
//Code for page a[a.aspx]
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if(Session["a"]==null)
   {
     Session["a"]="Some Value";
   }
   else
   {
     // do code if user visit the page again.
   } 
  }
```

Similarly you needs to do for all the pages.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I have a problem here. My page creates some controls in the page load and so if I am using session, then they will not be there on postback of the submit button. How do I fix it?

Comment: I hope u can Solve your problem by using ViewState[""].

Comment: ViewState["abc"]="abc"; String abc=(String)ViewState["abc"]

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies or session to keep a tab on the pages the user has gone through so you can prevent them from going back.